# Update console text from multiple threads not working

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console

I am executing/processing very big files in multi threaded mode in a console app.

When I don't update/write to the console from threads, for testing the whole process take about 1 minute.

But when I try to update/write to console from threads to show the progress, the process stuck and it never finishes (waited several minutes even hours). And also console text/window does not updated as it should.

**Update-1:** As requested by few kind responder, i added minimal code that can reproduce the same error/problem

Here is the code from the thread function/method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Large_Text_To_Small_Text
{
class Program
{
    static string sAppPath;
    static ArrayList objThreadList;

    private struct ThreadFileInfo
    {
        public string sBaseDir, sRFile;
        public int iCurFile, iTFile;
        public bool bIncludesExtension;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sFileDir;
        DateTime dtStart;


        Console.Clear();
        sAppPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        sFileDir = @"d:\Test";
        dtStart = DateTime.Now;
        ///process in multi threaded mode
        List<string> lFiles;

        lFiles = new List<string>();
        lFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(sFileDir, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        if (Directory.Exists(sFileDir + "-Processed") == true)
        {
            Directory.Delete(sFileDir + "-Processed", true);
        }
        Directory.CreateDirectory(sFileDir + "-Processed");
        sPrepareThreading();
        for (int iFLoop = 0; iFLoop < lFiles.Count; iFLoop++)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}/{1}", (iFLoop + 1), lFiles.Count));
            sThreadProcessFile(sFileDir + "-Processed", lFiles[iFLoop], (iFLoop + 1), lFiles.Count, Convert.ToBoolean(args[3]));

        }
        sFinishThreading();

        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtStart).ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
        return;
    }

    private static void sProcSO(object oThreadInfo)
    {
        var inputLines = new BlockingCollection<string>();
        long lACounter, lCCounter;
        ThreadFileInfo oProcInfo;

        lACounter = 0;
        lCCounter = 0;
        oProcInfo = (ThreadFileInfo)oThreadInfo;
        var readLines = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(oProcInfo.sRFile))
            {
                inputLines.Add(line);
                lACounter++;
            }
            inputLines.CompleteAdding();
        });

        var processLines = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(inputLines.GetConsumingEnumerable(), line =>
            {
                lCCounter++;
                /*
                    some process goes here
                */

                /*If i Comment out these lines program get stuck!*/
                //Console.SetCursorPosition(0, oProcInfo.iCurFile);
                //Console.Write(oProcInfo.iCurFile + " = " + lCCounter.ToString());
            });
        });

        Task.WaitAll(readLines, processLines);
    }

    private static void sPrepareThreading()
    {
        objThreadList = new ArrayList();
        for (var iTLoop = 0; iTLoop < 5; iTLoop++)
        {
            objThreadList.Add(null);
        }
    }

    private static void sThreadProcessFile(string sBaseDir, string sRFile, int iCurFile, int iTFile, bool bIncludesExtension)
    {
        Boolean bMatched;
        Thread oCurThread;
        ThreadFileInfo oProcInfo;

    Salma_RecheckThread:
        bMatched = false;
        for (int iTLoop = 0; iTLoop < 5; iTLoop++)
        {
            if (objThreadList[iTLoop] == null || ((System.Threading.Thread)(objThreadList[iTLoop])).IsAlive == false)
            {
                oProcInfo = new ThreadFileInfo()
                {
                    sBaseDir = sBaseDir,
                    sRFile = sRFile,
                    iCurFile = iCurFile,
                    iTFile = iTFile,
                    bIncludesExtension = bIncludesExtension
                };
                oCurThread = new Thread(sProcSO);
                oCurThread.IsBackground = true;
                oCurThread.Start(oProcInfo);
                objThreadList[iTLoop] = oCurThread;
                bMatched = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (bMatched == false)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            goto Salma_RecheckThread;
        }
    }


    private static void sFinishThreading()
    {
        Boolean bRunning;
    Salma_RecheckThread:
        bRunning = false;
        for (int iTLoop = 0; iTLoop < 5; iTLoop++)
        {
            if (objThreadList[iTLoop] != null && ((System.Threading.Thread)(objThreadList[iTLoop])).IsAlive == true)
            {
                bRunning = true;
            }
        }
        if (bRunning == true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            goto Salma_RecheckThread;
        }
    }

}
}
```

And here is the screenshot, if I try to update console window:

[image: Console Output]

You see? Nor the line number (`oProcInfo.iCurFile`) or the whole line is correct!

It should be like this:

```
1 = xxxxx
2 = xxxxx
3 = xxxxx
4 = xxxxx
5 = xxxxx
```

**Update-1:** To test just change the sFileDir to any folder that has some big text file or if you like you can download some big text files from following link:

```
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8aecfe05bb44e35582fc338f623ad43b20210602005845/bcdbb5
```

Am I missing any function/method to update console text from threads?

Comment: `lCCounter++` is not safe to do in the `ForEach()` delegate. But it wouldn't cause the the code you show above to fail to complete. That said, there's no evidence above that the code does in fact fail to complete. You're writing asynchronously to the console, in non-deterministic order, which can cause all kinds of unexpected visual appearance on the screen. But that doesn't mean the loop didn't _complete_. Please fix your question so it includes a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem.

Comment: @PeterDuniho,  thanks for your response, but do you want me to share whole code? that would make the question size very big :(

Comment: _"do you want me to share whole code?"_ -- no, of course not. Please read [mcve]. Then you'll know what you should share. If you still are unsure, read [ask], and pay close attention to the articles linked at the bottom of that page too.

Comment: We need to know what the `ThreadFileInfo` is, in order to be able to compile the code and experiment with it. Either the `ThreadFileInfo` is relevant to the question, and should be included, or it's just noise, and should be removed altogether.

Comment: Some thoughts: your code does zero error handling. In case the `readLines` task fails, the `processLines` task will get stuck, waiting forever for the completion of the `BlockingCollection`, and as a result the `Task.WaitAll(readLines, processLines);` will wait forever too. The `Parallel.ForEach` saturates the thread pool when the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` is not specified. You are advised to specify it. It also employs chunk partitioning by default, which you should probably disable with the `EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering` option.

Comment: You may find this interesting: [ParallelExtensionsExtras Tour – #4 – BlockingCollectionExtensions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-4-blockingcollectionextensions/)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias as requested i have updated my question with minimal code to reproduce the error.

Comment: I don't have your files, so the code you posted above can't run on my computer the way it runs on your computer. In other words, **it's not a [mcve]**. That said, from what you posted, it appears that you have tried to reinvent all the parallel-processing machinery that already exists in .NET. It's very likely you have done so incorrectly. Maybe someone else will find the problem by inspection, or maybe you'll fix the question. In the meantime, ...

Comment: ... I find the `goto` loops suspicious, along with the lack of thread synchronization for shared data. Without synchronization, your program state can become corrupted or threads can fail to observe data value changes made by other threads, which could then lead to those loops failing to exit. So you should look at that for now if you don't want to provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: @PeterDuniho, thanks a lot as you are trying your best to help me out. It's not that i don't want to share full solution/project, it's i don't know how to share it here, as i am not very experienced here. however, i have uploaded the full solution here, would you please download and try? https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5ca56759b6f0a107d6a4769e78722e6e20210602162633/7cfc3b

Comment: _"It's not that i don't want to share full solution/project, it's i don't know how to share it here"_ -- again, you're not expected to do that. You _are_ expected to use what you know about your real-world code, to write **a brand new** contrived code example that doesn't include the dependencies on elements that are not shareable, or are not practical to share (i.e. you can't expect SO users to download extra files, even just data files). ...

Comment: ... By "contrived" I mean that you replace aspects like processing files that can't be shared, with placeholder code that does something different -- perhaps even just waits with a `Thread.Sleep()` -- so that the example can be self-contained without those other dependencies.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, thanks again.. for the idea.. i have updated my project so now it no longer use outside/extra files, i hope you can now reproduce the error by using only the project files here: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/fa90070780a0252fd7127ac8becea18520210602172231/c8ac08

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233261/discussion-between-salmabegum-and-peter-duniho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce it. In my tests the process always runs to completion, without getting stuck. The output is all over the place though, because the two lines below are not synchronized:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, oProcInfo.iCurFile);
Console.Write(oProcInfo.iCurFile + " = " + lCCounter.ToString());
```

Each thread of the many threads involved in the computation invokes these two statements concurrently with the other threads. This makes it possible for one thread to preempt another, and move the cursor before the first thread has the chance to write in the console. To solve this problem you must add proper synchronization, and the easiest way to do it is to use the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement:

```
class Program
{
    static object _locker = new object();
```

And in the `sProcSO` method:

```
lock (_locker)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, oProcInfo.iCurFile);
    Console.Write(oProcInfo.iCurFile + " = " + lCCounter.ToString());
}
```

If you want to know more about thread synchronization, I recommend this online resource: [Threading in C# - Part 2: Basic Synchronization](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx)

If you would like to hear my opinion about the code in the question, and you don't mind receiving criticism, my opinion is that honestly the code is so much riddled with problems that the best course of action would be to throw it away and restart from scratch. Use of archaic data structures (`ArrayList`???), liberal use of casting from `object` to specific types, liberal use of the `goto` statement, use of hungarian notation in public type members, all make the code difficult to follow, and easy for bugs to creep in. I found particularly problematic that each file is processed concurrently with all other files using a dedicated thread, and then each dedicated thread uses a `ThreadPool` thread (`Task.Factory.StartNew`) to starts a parallel loop (`Parallel.ForEach`) with unconfigured `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. This setup ensures that the `ThreadPool` will be saturated so badly, that there is no hope that the availability of threads will ever match the demand. Most probably it will also result to a highly inefficient use of the storage device, especially if the hardware is a classic hard disk.

Comment: sir, that lock things somehow solve the issue, but it looks like if use lock/write to console the process take much longer if i don't? any idea? and also how can i hide/disable the blinking cursor, as the cursor moving from here and there to fast it's getting hard to read/understand the status :(

thanks for your help again

Comment: @SalmaBegum the `Console` class is thread-safe, so each call is synchronized internally anyway. By adding an extra layer of synchronization I would expect some added overhead, but it should be minuscule. Unless you are also doing other things while holding the lock. About how to improve the UI of the application, I have nothing specific to suggest. Maybe switching from a Console app to a WinForms app?

Answer (score -1):

Your freezing problem may not be C# or code related

on the top left of your console window, on the icon .. right click
select `Properties`
remove the option of `Quick Edit Mode` and `Insert Mode`

you can google that feature, but essentially manifests in the problem you describe above

The formatting problem on the other hand does seem to be, here you need to create a class that serializes writes to the console window from a singe thread. a consumer/producer pattern would work (you could use a `BlockingCollection` to implement this quite easily)